# GDAL VSIS3 and GetRasterBand

Tags: amazon-s3, gis, gdal

I'm trying to access some Landsat data from S3 without making local copies of the files. As a test I wanted to run a simple GetRasterBand on the file but I'm not sure how to go about treating a VSILFILE as a GDALDataset without downloading the file.

GDAL API guide states VSILFILE "cannot be used with any functions other than the "VSI*L" family of functions. They aren't "real" FILE objects."

Snip of my code :

```
VSILFILE *poVs3Dataset;
//GDALDataset  *poDataset;
GDALRasterBand  *poBand;
char * path = (char *)"/vsis3/landsat-pds/c1/L8/139/045/LC08_L1TP_139045_20170304_20170316_01_T1/LC08_L1TP_139045_20170304_20170316_01_T1_B1.TIF";

GDALAllRegister();
VSIInstallS3FileHandler();
CPLSetConfigOption( "AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID", "XXX" );
CPLSetConfigOption( "AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY", "XXX" );

poVs3Dataset = VSIFOpenL(path, "r");

poBand = poVs3Dataset->GetRasterBand( 1 );
```

Which ultimately and understandably fails

g++ -g -L/usr/local/lib -lgdal stats.cpp
error: ‘VSILFILE’ has no member named ‘GetRasterBand’

Are there any good C++ examples out there I could work through?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Setting my environment variables prior to calling the executable seemed to help:

$> env AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=xxx AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=xxx ./a.out /vsis3/landsat-pds/c1/L8/139/045/LC08_L1TP_139045_20170304_20170316_01_T1/LC08_L1TP_139045_20170304_20170316_01_T1_B1.TIF

This is now my test code to prove to myself I can access with both GDALOpenEx & VSIFOpenExL which works in case it helps someone else:

```
VSILFILE *fpL;
GDALDataset  *poDataset;
GDALRasterBand  *poBand;
char * path = (char *)"/vsis3/landsat-pds/c1/L8/139/045/LC08_L1TP_139045_20170304_20170316_01_T1/LC08_L1TP_139045_20170304_20170316_01_T1_B1.TIF";

VSIStatBufL sStat;
const char* const apszAllowedDrivers[] = { "GTiff", NULL };

GDALAllRegister();

poDataset = reinterpret_cast<GDALDataset*>(GDALOpenEx(path, GDAL_OF_READONLY | GDAL_OF_RASTER | GDAL_OF_VERBOSE_ERROR, NULL, NULL, NULL));

if( poDataset == NULL )
{
  std::cout << "Couldn't open " << std::endl;
}
poBand = poDataset->GetRasterBand( 1 );
int   nXSize = poBand->GetXSize();
int   nYSize = poBand->GetYSize();
std::cout << "nXSize : " << nXSize << std::endl;
std::cout << "nYSize : " << nYSize << std::endl;

fpL = VSIFOpenExL(path, "rb", 1);

if( fpL != NULL )
{
  ....
  works!!!
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped me figure out remote access to s3 from gdal. Another useful `ENV` variable is `AWS_S3_ENDPOINT` which defaults to `s3.amazonaws.com`. This can be an issue when you need something like this `s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com` for your endpoint. The [gdal virtual file system documentation](https://www.gdal.org/gdal_virtual_file_systems.html) is also useful.